# Get all active tokens for your application

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Is there a way that we can get all active oauth tokens for connected realm to application.
I need this as a fail safe. If e.g. user authenticates realm and we fail to save token and secret for realm, user is connected to our app, we are being charged but we cannot fetch any data so we need a service that will fetch currently active tokens and secrets.
Thank you

Comment: Your application should be storing and encrypting the access tokens for each realm.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to, you can go to the connections report in appcenter and disconnect the user manually. This will invalidate the tokens and they will need to re-authorize the connection.

Comment: This also stops the billing for that connection.

Answer (score 0):

Intuit does not provide any API that does this. Since providing an API like this would be a potential massive security hole, I wouldn't get your hopes up about this ever becoming available.

Have you looked into why your service is failing to save the token/secret/realm? That sounds like the place to start...